# Take a snapshot for a table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table called "col" - This table is updated every month.

what i want is to take snapshot (updated version) for that table every period of time.

my question is how to take snapshot for that table in oracle ?

EDIT: my DB version is 19c

Comment: what type of snapshot , is it for a Data warehouse or just a monthly copy of the table with a different name ? How big is the table i.e. number of rows, and how many inserts/updates are in a month ?

Comment: yes - monthly copy for the data and million of inserts every month is done

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just run a "CTAS" aka "CREATE TABLE [your table name plus some date string] AS SELECT * FROM [the table];

```
CREATE TABLE [SNAPSHOT NAME] as SELECT * FROM [TABLE NAME];
```

Note: this works a lot of places, not just in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `SNAPSHOT TABLE` with an identical structure as the original column with an additional column `SNAPSHOT_DATE`

Example

```
CREATE TABLE COL_SNAPSHOT AS
SELECT 
cast (null as DATE) as SNAPSHOT_DATE,
a.*
from COL a
WHERE 1=0;
```

THis statement creates an e,pty table with the additional column. You may *partition* the table an the column `SNAPSHOT_DATE`if you are lincenced for it.

Now once a month you *take a new snapshot* using following insert

```
INSERT INTO COL_SNAPSHOT
(SNAPSHOT_DATE, ... all columns from COL ...)
SELECT 
   sysdate SNAPSHOT_DATE, ... all columns from COL ...
FROM COL;
```

You save the current state of the table and additionaly in the column `SNAPSHOT_DATE` is the *timestamp* of the snapshot.